# How to get the SQL String From JPQLQuery

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I'm using EclipseLink.

I've a JPQLquery and I want to get the sql String..
Now I'm doing in this way:

```
EJBQueryImpl qi = (EJBQueryImpl)jpqlQuery;
String sqlQueryString = qi.getDatabaseQuery().getSQLString();
```

The problem is that in the sqlQueryString the constant are replaced with ?

I've tried to get the values navigating the expressions trees (`getSelectionCriteria()` and `getHavingCriteria()`) but in this way I loose the type...

Do any one ever have a problem like this one?

Comment: As a follow up question: how do I get the SQL string when I do a em.persist(pojoDbObject)?

Answer (score 4):

Quoted from the [EclipseLink FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA#How_to_get_the_SQL_for_a_Query.3F):

> To see the SQL for a JPA Query you can
>   enable logging on FINE or lower.
>
> To get the SQL for a specific Query at
>   runtime you can use the DatabaseQuery
>   API.

```
Session session = em.unwrap(JpaEntityManager.class).getActiveSession();
DatabaseQuery databaseQuery = ((EJBQueryImpl)query).getDatabaseQuery();
databaseQuery.prepareCall(session, new DatabaseRecord());
String sqlString = databaseQuery.getSQLString();
```

> This SQL will contain ? for
>   parameters. To get the SQL translated
>   with the arguments you need a
>   DatabaseRecord with the parameter
>   values.

```
Session session = em.unwrap(JpaEntityManager.class).getActiveSession();
DatabaseQuery databaseQuery = ((EJBQueryImpl)query).getDatabaseQuery();
String sqlString = databaseQuery.getTranslatedSQLString(session, recordWithValues);
```

Comment: What is recordWithValues? Is it possible to get it from DatabaseQuery or EJBQueryImpl?

Comment: For future reference: `recordWithValues` should be `databaseQuery.getTranslationRow()` (source: https://dzone.com/articles/eclipselink-how-get-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that works:

```
public static void logJpaQuery(EntityManager em, TypedQuery tq){
        org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session session = em.unwrap(JpaEntityManager.class).getActiveSession();        
        DatabaseQuery dq = ((EJBQueryImpl) tq).getDatabaseQuery();
        AbstractRecord translationRow = dq.getTranslationRow();        
        dq.prepareCall(session, new DatabaseRecord());        
        String translatedSQLString = dq.getTranslatedSQLString(session, translationRow);
        log.trace("translated sql is: {}", translatedSQLString);
    }
```